# Define nested strucType

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-option

I have the following question:
Having an Option of List of elements I want to transform it into a List of elements by avoiding the use of .get on the Option.
Below is the snippet of code that I want to change : Any idea how to modify this please :

```
val receivedMessages = PubSubClient.getPulledMessages(client,subscriptionFullName,pullRequest).get
        store(receivedMessages
          .map(x => {
            val sm = new PubsubSparkMessage
            sm.message = x.getMessage
            sm
          })
          .iterator)
```

I want to replace the .get in the line  `PubSubClient.getPulledMessages(client,subscriptionFullName,pullRequest).get`

Answer (score 0):

Taking this example:

```
val maybeList = Some(List("hello", "here"))
```

When printing this:

```
println(maybeList) // Some(List(hello, here))
```

To fix this you can do this:

```
maybeList.toSeq.flatMap(x=> x) // List(hello, here)
```

Or if you prefer with for comprehension:

```
for{
  list <- maybeList.toSeq
  elem <- list
} yield elem
```

Or in short:

```
maybeList.toSeq.flatten
```

Here the [Scala Fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/GcWLdVP/2) if you want to play with this.

With your Example - it looks like this:

```
val receivedMessages = PubSubClient.getPulledMessages(client,subscriptionFullName,pullRequest)

store(receivedMessages.toSeq
      .flatMap(x => {
        val sm = new PubsubSparkMessage
        sm.message = x.getMessage
        sm
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will accomplish what you want:

```
def listOptToList[T](listOpt: Option[List[T]): List[T] = listOpt.toList.flatten
```

So your code would look something like:

```
val receivedMessages = PubSubClient.getPulledMessages(client,subscriptionFullName,pullRequest)

store(listOptToList(receivedMessages.map { x =>
    val sm = new PubSubSparkMessage
    sm.message = x.getMessage
    sm
  }).iterator)
```